# Cacls, full permission, local names

Tags: windows, batch

I tried to use cacls to give "Everyone" group access to certain folder. And I failed. As I understand the reason is i'm trying to use groupname in english while my windows is localized. Attempt to use localized groupname succeded. I can't predict language of target system. How can I grant permissions on folder regardless of Windows localization?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: i want to use cacls in bat-file on wide range of systems. From **Win2K** to **Win7**. That's why i can't ise **icacls**.

Comment: Is it OK to replace the existing permissions on the folder?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, I think.

Comment: The /s option to cacls will do what you want, but I'm not sure which version of the OS introduced it.  If cacls /s didn't exist in Windows 2000, then I think you're stuck - you'll probably have to ship an executable along with the batch file.

Comment: tried to run icacls from win7 on winxp. no luck. says not proper win32 executable. so can't ship executable

Comment: I meant an executable you'd written yourself, or gotten someone to write for you.  It would be about ten lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best i could do is use version number checking, if winVersion >= 6 then use icacls
else use xcacls.vbs which i ship with my script. Though xcacls is extremly slow, it works for me for now. In future - we'll see.